# How come I can't url encode this URL in node.js?

Tags: javascript, url, encoding, node.js

```
$node
querystring = require('querystring')
var dict = { 'q': 'what\'s up' };
var url = 'http://google.com/?q=' + querystring.stringify(dict);
url = encodeURIComponent(url);
console.log(url);
```

The result is this:

```
"http://google.com/?q=q=what's%20up"
```

Notice how the single quote is not encoded correctly. Is there something wrong with the node.js module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is encoded correctly, if you type the same query into google sear field manually you will get this address:

```
http://www.google.cz/#hl=cs&cp=8&gs_id=u&xhr=t&q=what's+up&pf=p&sclient=psy&site=&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=what's+u&aq=0&aqi=g5&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=792ecf51920895b2&biw=1276&bih=683
```

note that `&q=what's+up&` part

and `encodeURIComponent` is not a Node.js module, but part of standard javascript library

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

manual workaround:

```
$node
querystring = require('querystring')
var dict = { 'q': 'what\'s up' };
var url = 'http://google.com/?q=' + querystring.stringify(dict);
url = encodeURIComponent(url);
url = url.replace(/'/g,"%27");
```

Comment: Well, I need it encoded because Facebook's Graph API breaks when the single quote is in the "name" field.

Comment: If you search "What's up" in youtube , notice that it encodes it.

Comment: `Graph API breaks`, how it breaks? you have some debug msg or so? what API call do you use?

Comment: see the youtube thing, i'll add workaround code to my answer in a minute

Answer (score 12):

The `'` is allowed in plain in the URI query. Here are the corresponding [production rules for the URI query as per RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4):

> ```
> query         = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
> pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
> unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
> pct-encoded   = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
> sub-delims    = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
>               / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
> ```

As you can see, *sub-delims* contains a plain `'`. So the result is valid.